# Get MAX() on column in two tables

Tags: sql, mysql, max

I have two tables which both have the column DateTime.

How can I get the MAX() DateTime?

The shorter/simpler the better, because this is just part of a larger query.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the [GREATEST function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest):

```
SELECT GREATEST((SELECT MAX(column) 
                   FROM TABLE_1),
                (SELECT MAX(column) 
                   FROM TABLE_2))
```

Using UNIONs:

```
SELECT MAX(col)
  FROM (SELECT col FROM TABLE_1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT col FROM TABLE_2)
```

Use `UNION ALL` for this - it's faster because it doesn't remove duplicates, and it doesn't matter if duplicates are returned by the subquery in this example.

Comment: The second solution require setting alias for the derived table: `SELECT MAX(col) FROM (...) AS alias_name`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT MAX(thedate) FROM (
    SELECT mydate as thedate FROM TABLE1

    UNION

    SELECT anotherdate as thedate FROM TABLE2
) as tablealias
```